# Imported FBX rigs break in Blender

Tags: animation, rigging, unity, .fbx

I am sure this is a very common issue, but nonetheless I couldn't find a solution.

I have many rigged FBX models which animate perfectly in Unity. However, I often want to modify them, so I import them into blender. Even with no changes, if I re-save or re-export the imported fbx, the models (in the new .blend or .fbx) no longer animate in unity- no motion at all, or a few times in the past, a dramatic twisting/skewing of the new model when trying the same animation that worked on the original fbx.

I'm positive that this is a common mistake for new users, but somehow I have failed to master this for years, despite searching for answers every time. What am I missing?

Many thanks.